# How to load dynamacilly an ArrayList value into editable TableView column cell in JavaFx

Tags: arraylist, javafx, tableview, tablecell, tablecolumn

I am trying to load a `TableView` with `ArrayList` Value in editable cell. I have following `ReadOnlyStringWrapper` loading the `ArrayList` but I need editable, how?

```
ObservableList<String> infoHeader = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
tableView = new TableView(FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        infoHeader));
tableView.setId("index-table");
TableColumn<String, String> headerColumn = new TableColumn<>("HEADER");
headerColumn.setCellValueFactory((p) -> {
    return new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(p.getValue());
});


tableView.getColumns().addAll(headerColumn);
tableView.setEditable(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `ReadOnlyStringWrapper` is not necessary here, since you never use the `ReadOnlyStringProperty` provided by it. `SimpleStringProperty` would be enough.

Furthermore this is just unnecessary:

```
ObservableList<String> infoHeader = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
...
FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        infoHeader)
...
```

It just copies the contents of a empty `ObservableList` to a new `ObservableList`. Simply using `FXCollections.observableArrayList()` as the second expression achieves the same effect.

---

You can write the value to the items list by using the `onEditCommit` handler for the `TableColumn`, but you also need to use a `cellFactory` that returns editable cells, such as `TextFieldTableCell`s. Furthermore every item still needs to be added from code.

```
// data list with sample entry
ObservableList<String> infoHeader = FXCollections.observableArrayList("something");

tableView = new TableView<>(infoHeader);
tableView.setId("index-table");

TableColumn<String, String> headerColumn = new TableColumn<>("HEADER");
headerColumn.setCellValueFactory((p) -> {
    return new SimpleStringProperty(p.getValue());
});
headerColumn.setOnEditCommit(evt -> {
    // change list item corresponding to this cell
    evt.getTableView().getItems().set(evt.getTablePosition().getRow(), evt.getNewValue());
});
headerColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());

tableView.getColumns().addAll(headerColumn);
tableView.setEditable(true);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. But I am getting same results as before using SimpleStringProperty. I just copy the whole code of yours. The cell is still not editable. Am I missing something? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @SadequerRahman It should be editable, unless you change `TableColumn.editable` to `false`. Furthermore the editing state is entered, on a double click of a non-empty cell.